# Successful connection to NordVPN through openvpn client blocks internet connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am using my Ubuntu 20.10 and its `openvpn' client to connect to NordVPN's servers through TCP.

In particular I have followed the instructions [here](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1047409422/How-can-I-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Terminal.htm).

When I try to connect to the VPN, openvpn returns

> Initialization Sequence Completed

but my internet connection is effectively blocked. I cannot reach any website using Firefox, and if I run

`ping google.com`

I obtain

> ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Here are the logs from the command line:

```
$ sudo openvpn it158.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
Wed Feb  3 02:24:41 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Aug 18 2020
Wed Feb  3 02:24:41 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
 Enter Auth Username: <ABRIDGED>
 Enter Auth Password: <ABRIDGED>           
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 WARNING: --ping should normally be used with --ping-restart or --ping-exit
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]217.138.219.131:443
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
Wed Feb  3 02:24:54 2021 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]217.138.219.131:443 [nonblock]
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]217.138.219.131:443
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]217.138.219.131:443
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]217.138.219.131:443, sid=eb958290 12fbf35f
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=2, C=PA, O=NordVPN, CN=NordVPN Root CA
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=PA, O=NordVPN, CN=NordVPN CA5
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 VERIFY KU OK
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=it158.nordvpn.com
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 4096 bit RSA
Wed Feb  3 02:24:55 2021 [it158.nordvpn.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]217.138.219.131:443
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 SENT CONTROL [it158.nordvpn.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 103.86.96.100,dhcp-option DNS 103.86.99.100,sndbuf 524288,rcvbuf 524288,explicit-exit-notify,comp-lzo no,route-gateway 10.7.0.1,topology subnet,ping 60,ping-restart 180,ifconfig 10.7.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: --explicit-exit-notify can only be used with --proto udp
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: compression parms modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: --sndbuf/--rcvbuf options modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->425984] S=[87040->425984]
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1659
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.169.180.254/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp0s20f3 HWADDR=d0:c6:37:d9:cc:31
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.7.0.2/24 broadcast 10.7.0.255
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 /sbin/ip route add 217.138.219.131/32 via 10.169.180.254
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.0.1
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.0.1
Wed Feb  3 02:24:56 2021 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the DNS server.

Apparently if you connect to the VPN my DNS doesn't respond anymore.

I have switched to Google's DNS.

Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and put this inside of it:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Then reboot.